# What is the best way to automate the creation of hundreds of tasks per project?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I am planning for an SP site that tracks a registration process. Each registration will have a hundred tasks or more.

At a high level, I think I should create a task list that would serve as a template that would hold the hundred tasks. Next, I think I should create a custom workflow that would create a new registration and make a copy of the hundred tasks from the template list into a registration task list.

Does that seem like a reasonable approach? Does anyone else have a better approach they could recommend?

I have SP 2013 and pretty much any tool I want at my disposal.